# How to keep log file in Spring Cloud Data Flow?

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

My Spring Cloud Data Flow deleted log file in folder after I stopped it.
Why SCDF does that and How can I keep these log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the logging configuration in the logback config file and pass it as a configuration properties for the SCDF server. Assuming you are trying this with the `local` data flow server, you can refer [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-local-logging) documentation for logback configuration.

Comment: How about the log of each task/job ?

Comment: The logs of the applications are managed by the deployer implementation. Also, it is exposed by the `/runtime/apps` endpoint as well as the `Runtime` tab in the SCDF Dashboard.

Comment: how about "deleteFilesOnExit". It's default value is true? Does it make the log file gone after stop SCDF?

Comment: Yes, by default this `local` deployer property is set to `true` and it will enable the stdout, stderr directories to be deleted upon undeploy operation.

Comment: Could you give me the properties to set it into false?